# Include Makefile and Echo Variables Inside Multiple Makefiles

Tags: makefile, multiple-makefiles

Inside a Makefile I have recently had to look at, it includes this `include $(MAKERULES)`

Now to me, I would think somewhere at the top of the makefile it has `MAKERULES = xyz` but it does not. So I print out MAKERULES

```
test:

    @echo "Rules: $(MAKERULES)"
```

Then I do make test. It runs and it prints out another Makefile Location, Makefile2.

X/Y/Z/Makefile2 path. I go inside this Makefile and attempt to write out some echo statements so I can see what is printing, but nothing prints out.

Is it possible to print out variables from another Makefile (Makefile2) that my local Makefile (Makefile) references to?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which variables are you trying to print?

Comment: I'll define that, one moment, I apologize

Comment: **Which variables are you trying to print?** All of the variables defined in Makefile2, or just a few specific ones?

Comment: Just a few specific ones. But, I guess if I could print them all, that'd be fine too. Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You haven't shown us your attempt to display those variables, so we can't tell you why it didn't work. (Well, *I* can't.)

Here is how I'd do it:

```
$(info the variable FOO contains $(FOO))
```

If you want to do this for several variables:

```
$(foreach X, FOO BAR BAZ, $(info $(X) is $($(X))))
```

And the list of all currently defined global variables is `.VARIABLES`, so you can use "$(.VARIABLES)" in place of "FOO BAR BAZ" to print all of them.

Comment: Interesting, will try this out tomorrow, ty.